# php object variable as classname

Tags: php, class, static

when I want to statically access the class JSON using an variable it is possible.

Code:

```
<?php
$classname = "JSON";
$classname::echo_output();
?>
```

But when I want to use an object variable to statically access the class it fails.
code:

```
<?php
class someclass{
public $classname = "JSON";
    public function __construct(){
        $this->classname::echo_output();
    }
}
?>
```

Try it yourself.

How I solved it was $classname = $this->classname;
But is there any other possible way to solve this?

Comment: Where is the "echo_output()" function defined?

Comment: From the looks of it you're using a custom `JSON` class and have already solved the problem you were experiencing. Is there another issue you're having?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [call_user_func](https://www.php.net/function.call-user-func) function in order to achieve this

```
<?php

class someclass{

public $classname = "JSON";

    public function __construct(){
        call_user_func([$this->classname, 'echo_output']);
    }

}
?>
```

Comment: This way i cant add parameters can i?

Comment: @Ismail You actually can add parameters, just call it like so: call_user_func(['JSON', 'echo_output'], $param1, $param2, ... , $paramN); Look it up from the manual.

Answer (score 0):

If echo_output actually exists in the class your calling, this should work but you have to assign the property to a variable first.

```
public function __construct(){
    $classname = $this->classname;
    $classname::echo_output();
}
```

Comment: You're right, I assumed it would work but then went to read up on it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php

Answer (score 0):

By PHP 5.4+ you can do this with `ReflectionClass` in a single line.

```
(new \ReflectionClass($this->classname))->getMethod('echo_output')->invoke(null);
```

under PHP 5.4

```
call_user_func(array($this->classname, 'echo_output'));
```

but I don't recommend this.

Instead of using static methods, you should create instances, inject them, and call their methods...

```
interface Helper{
    public function echo_output();
}

class JSONHelper implements Helper {
    ...
}

class someclass{
    public function __construct(Helper $helper){
        $helper->echo_output();
    }
}

new someclass(new JSONHelper()); //multiple instances
new someclass(JSONHelper::getInstance()); //singleton
new someclass($helperFactory->createHelper()); //factory
new someclass($container->getHelper()); //IoC container
```

Answer (score 0):

By some research and javascript knowledge this solution would be the simpliest.

```
<?php
class someclass{
public $classname = "JSON";
    public function __construct(){
        $that = (array) $this;
        $that["classname"]::echo_output();
    }
}
?>
```

Just cast objects to arrays.

This way you don't have to define a variable for each dynamic classname.